# Testing ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing

I am exposing a service using asp.net web API. each get/put/post calls internally corresponding WCF method after doing some logic like converting passed objects.
(using `apicontroller`, not `odatacontroller`)

I would like to test the written 'logic' but I can't make the WCF call yet as it is being written by some other team (for which I will write stub). I'm planning to write a test hook in each get/put.

My requirement is to write simple client code (not using paid tool, but a simple .exe which can test a running service) to test the logic written.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test Web API i suggest using this neat tool called RestSharp, its free not paid

Here is the URL : http://restsharp.org/

You can get it through Nuget Package Manager.

Once you install it, you would be able to test your service pretty easily.

It has examples to get you started on the first page.